# SQL Conditional Join With Same Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a join clause in a query like this.

```
SELECT Table1.Number

FROM Table1

JOIN Table2 AS Table on Table2.Table1_ID = Table1.ID
JOIN Table3 AS Table on Table3.Table1_ID = Table1.ID

JOIN OtherTable on Table.ID = OtherTable.Table_ID
```

I want to conditionally join only one of the tables 2 or 3 depending on Table.Number and retain the alias name so that other tables will still join to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
select T1.*, OT.*
from Table1 as T1
    inner join (
        select 1 as Number, T.Col, T.Table1_ID, T.Table_ID from Table2
        union all
        select 2 as Number, T.Col, T.Table1_ID, T.Table_ID from Table3
    ) as T2 on T2.Number = T1.Number and T2.Table1_ID = T1.ID
    inner join OtherTable as OT on OT.Table_ID = T2.Table_ID
```

or (could be less efficient)

```
select T1.*, OT.*
from Table1 as T1
    left outer join Table2 as TMP1 on TMP1.Table1_ID = T1.ID and T1.Number = 1
    left outer join Table3 as TMP2 on TMP2.Table1_ID = T1.ID and T1.Number = 2
    cross apply (select isnull(TMP1.Table_ID, TMP2.Table_ID) as Table_ID) as T2
    inner join OtherTable as OT on OT.Table_ID = T2.Table_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the two tables have the same columns (or at least a common column sub-set):

```
SELECT Table1.Number,Table.Id,OtherTable.Id
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table2
  WHERE Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table3
  WHERE Table3.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
) AS Table
JOIN OtherTable 
ON Table.ID = OtherTable.Table_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trick it by unioning the two tables into one derived table.

```
SELECT Table1.Number
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT ID, Table1_ID FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Table1_ID FROM TABLE3) t ON t.Table1_ID = t1.ID
JOIN OtherTable o ON t.ID = o.Table_ID
```

But I think the table structure is wrong here.

o.Table_ID being able to point to two different tables will make it impossible to enforce referential integrity through constraints. Also, an ID might exist in both tables at the same time.

Depending on the sitation (hard to guess with these fake names), I would make two different columns in OtherTable, make an FK in Table2 and Table3 to OtherTable, or make an extra table to hold the relations.